# Does not work with GoogleMaps V2 and AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-android-api-2

I do not understand why I can not start the map?

To the project as a library "google-play-services_lib" hooked. In the emulator application load.
But I can not see the map.
Now get this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.ai.mi.maptrack/de.ai.mi.maptrack.activities.TravelMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
```

I assume that the problem is a bad setup "AndroidManifest" but do not understand what's wrong, tell me.

Perhaps the problem is not in the correct position of the classes and registration "AndroidManifest"?

In Google console to generate a key to this package.

```
MY_KEY;de.ai.mi.maptrack
```

I did everything like this.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.ai.mi.maptrack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="de.ai.mi.maptrack.activities.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="de.ai.mi.maptrack.activities.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_KEY_FROM_GOOGLE_CONSOLE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.StartMenuActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activities.TravelDescriptionActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.TravelMapActivity" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

travel_map_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

TravelMapActivity

```
package de.ai.mi.maptrack.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import de.ai.mi.maptrack.R;

public class TravelMapActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travel_map_activity);
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to extends the fragmentactivity not activity.

> ```
> public class TravelMapActivity  extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
> ```

Comment: But in Google tutorial on another.

Comment: Works! But I see only a blank page. Without cells as it was before. In what could be the reason?